# English practice

Tags: spoken-english

Iam a new learner but i canť  completely understand English films or distinguish between the words when I hear it

And
What is the best way to acquire the sense of language?

And is that take too much time?

Comment: Keep practicing. And yes, it's going to take some time. Good luck!

Comment: Keep watching movies and shows with subtitles. Watch the same thing with and without subtitles until you can understand without them.